# How to add HTTP Header Content-Length to Google Translate API call?

Tags: python, google-translate

I have this piece of code from https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text#translate-translate-text-python

```
from google.cloud import translate
import six

def translate_text(text,target):

    translate_client = translate.Client()

    if isinstance(text, six.binary_type):
        text = text.decode('utf-8')

    result = translate_client.translate(
        text,
        target_language=target)
    print(u'Text: {}'.format(result['input']))
    print(u'Translation: {}'.format(result['translatedText']))
    print(u'Detected source language: {}'.format(
        result['detectedSourceLanguage']))

txtTranslate = 'a long long text...'
conteudo = translate_text(txtTranslate,target='pt')
```

It works well. The problem is when I have a very long text to translate, I'm getting error 411 Content-Length Required.
How I'm supposed to add the Content-Length header to the HTTP request, and what function do I use to count the length?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to send data in body instead of in query, and it should fix this!